# Guessing the pattern: f(43)=13, f(79)=40,

Tags: mathematics, pattern

I have these numbers and I couldn't guess the pattern of this question 
it might be easy or it might be hard whatever these are the numbers 
$$ f(43) = 13\\ f(79) = 40\\ f(111) = 120\\f(138)=161\\f(169) = 247\\f(256) = ??? $$ I tried to sum digits of the number but get nothing 
can any one help /:

Comment: Can you tell us a bit about where this puzzle comes from?

Comment: There are an infinite number of functions that will agree at the 5 points given but have different values at 256.

Comment: @chepner This objection applies to any "what's next in this sequence" question. Please move along.

Answer (score 29):

The answer is:

> **619**

**Reason:**
 `f(x*10 + y) = … where x: N, y: [0, 9]`

> Because: $f(x*10+y) = x^2 - y$
>  $$f(43) = 4^2 -3 = 13$$ $$f(79) = 7^2 - 9 = 40$$ $$f(111) = 11^2 - 1 = 120$$ $$f(138) = 13^2 - 8 = 161$$
>  So: $$f(256) = 25^2 - 6 = 619$$

Comment: Why not explain notation like `f(x*10 + y) = … where x: N, y: [0, 9]`?

Comment: @user28434 As you wish

Answer (score 15):

@rudha I am not allowed to make comments yet.  I like your answer.

Since I am new to this notation style, I found the notation confusing because:

> Using $f(xy)$ notation, $f(111)$ is ambiguous to me, as $x$ could be $1$, and $y$ could be $11$, such that $f(111)$ could also become $1^2 - 11$ resulting in $-10$.  But, even before that, I thought $xy$ meant $x \times y$.

So, I just wanted to reformat it in the imperative style I am used to:

> $$ f(xy) = x^2 - y $$
>  becomes:
>  $$ f(z) = \lfloor z/10 \rfloor^2 - (z\bmod10)\,,$$
>  which becomes, in pseudocode:
>  $$ f(z) = \mathrm{power}( \mathrm{floor}(z/10) , 2) - ( \mathrm{modulus}(z,10) ) $$

So, in JavaScript (which is easy to test in web browsers) it would be:

> function f(z) { return Math.pow( Math.floor(z/10), 2) - z%10; }

Comment: It could also be shown as `f(x \Vert y)`, which produces $f(x \Vert y)$, as long as you clarify the meaning. $\Vert$ is a symbol commonly used for digit concatenation, per [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Concatenation.html) and [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/423602). (I do like showing the explicit formula for a single number $z$, but I think this conveys @rudra's intention better.)

Answer (score 5):

I believe the answer is:

> 3166

Reasoning:

> By calculating the quartic regression equation [(See Wolframalpha.com)](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=quartic%20fit%20%7B43%2C13%7D%2C%20%7B79%2C40%7D%2C%20%7B111%2C120%7D%2C%7B138%2C161%7D%2C%20%7B169%2C247%7D) the number 256 can be substituted into the equation yielding f(256)= 3166

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour]!**) To be a *puzzle* and not an "identify the mathematical sequence" question, this would have to be something that goes beyond mechanically fitting a formula to the literal numbers and then grinding out the next entry (see, for example, our [guidance to number sequence posters](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5712)).  See other answers which would be more in the spirit of what to expect, and see if you can come up with a reasonable but interesting pattern!

Comment: btw it's wolframalpha not wolframalfa